# C unistd.h write() command write extra character

Tags: c, linux, cp

I've been trying to do c programming implementation of cp command in unix/linux by using system calls (read(), write(), open(), close()).

But when I run my program through terminal by copying my source code of this program to the same directory with name change (the source code is about 300 lines)

and when I open that output file , it has more character than the original file.

The extra line is the same as 200ish line. Where does it came from?

here's the screenshot [when compile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNR3Y.png)

[argp.c](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OHPlX1cWyr4LGTJnVRjBK2wVctvvy0co)

[123.c](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aUYafhnLBKZWU3Tciiv0KTl_Ivb0ikkL)

This is the source code near the end of the original file(argp.c). You will see how I use the read write method.

```
 while (count - ind > 1) {

        strcpy(cdir, argv[argc-1]);

        if (!isFile(cdir)) {
            strcat(cdir, basename(arguments.argv[ind]));
        }

        if (arguments.update) {
            stat(cdir,&stDest);
            stat(arguments.argv[ind],&stSrc);
            if (difftime(stDest.st_mtim.tv_sec, stSrc.st_mtim.tv_sec) > 0 ) {
                printf("Destination file is newer\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }

        //open source file
        src = open(arguments.argv[ind],O_RDONLY);
        //if source file can't be opened
        if (src == -1) {
            printf("\nError opening file %s errno = %d\n",arguments.argv[ind],errno);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        //open target file
        if (arguments.force) {
            //with -f option(default)
            tgt = open(cdir, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC , S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWUSR | S_IWGRP | S_IWOTH);
        } else {
            //with -n option
            tgt = open(cdir, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_EXCL , S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWUSR | S_IWGRP | S_IWOTH);
        }
        //if the target file cannot be read or already exist(with -n option)
        if (tgt == -1) {
            printf("File exist or it's not a file.\nCan't copy.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        //read source file


        //write target file
        while ((pos = read(src, buffer, BUFFERSIZE)) > 0) {
           if (write(tgt, buffer, BUFFERSIZE) != pos) {
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
           }
        }

        //if the source file cannot be read
        if (pos == -1) {
            printf("\nError in reading data from %s\n",arguments.argv[ind]);
        }

        //close source file
        if (close(src) == -1) {
            printf("\nError in closing file %s\n",arguments.argv[ind]);
        }

        //close target file
        if (close(tgt) == -1) {
            printf("\nError in closing file %s\n",cdir);
        }

        ind++;
    }

    if (arguments.verbose) {
        printf("Copy successfully!\n");
    }

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

}
```

This is the source code near the end of the copy file(123.c)

```
        while (count - ind > 1) {

        strcpy(cdir, argv[argc-1]);

        if (!isFile(cdir)) {
            strcat(cdir, basename(arguments.argv[ind]));
        }

        if (arguments.update) {
            stat(cdir,&stDest);
            stat(arguments.argv[ind],&stSrc);
            if (difftime(stDest.st_mtim.tv_sec, stSrc.st_mtim.tv_sec) > 0 ) {
                printf("Destination file is newer\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }

        //open source file
        src = open(arguments.argv[ind],O_RDONLY);
        //if source file can't be opened
        if (src == -1) {
            printf("\nError opening file %s errno = %d\n",arguments.argv[ind],errno);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        //open target file
        if (arguments.force) {
            //with -f option(default)
            tgt = open(cdir, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC , S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWUSR | S_IWGRP | S_IWOTH);
        } else {
            //with -n option
            tgt = open(cdir, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_EXCL , S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWUSR | S_IWGRP | S_IWOTH);
        }
        //if the target file cannot be read or already exist(with -n option)
        if (tgt == -1) {
            printf("File exist or it's not a file.\nCan't copy.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        //read source file


        //write target file
        while ((pos = read(src, buffer, BUFFERSIZE)) > 0) {
           if (write(tgt, buffer, BUFFERSIZE) != pos) {
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
           }
        }

        //if the source file cannot be read
        if (pos == -1) {
            printf("\nError in reading data from %s\n",arguments.argv[ind]);
        }

        //close source file
        if (close(src) == -1) {
            printf("\nError in closing file %s\n",arguments.argv[ind]);
        }

        //close target file
        if (close(tgt) == -1) {
            printf("\nError in closing file %s\n",cdir);
        }

        ind++;
    }

if (arguments.verbose) {
    printf("Copy successfully!\n");
}

exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

}
it(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        //read source file


        //write target file
        while ((pos = read(src, buffer, BUFFERSIZE)) > 0) {
           if (write(tgt, buffer, BUFFERSIZE) != pos) {
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
           }
        }

        //if the source file cannot be read
        if (pos == -1) {
            printf("\nError in reading data from %s\n",arguments.argv[ind]);
        }

        //close source file
        if (close(src) == -1) {
            printf("\nError in closing file %s\n",arguments.argv[ind]);
        }

        //close target file
        if (close(tgt) == -1) {
            printf("\nError in closing file %s\n",cdir);
        }

        ind++;
    }

if (arguments.verbose) {
    printf("Copy successfully!\n");
}

exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

}
```

Comment: So what is different between them? There are tools that show what’s changed. Also why are you writing always the same amount of data regardless what read says it read?

Comment: Please do not paste text messages as screenshot but add it as text into your question. And provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always try to read/write `BUFFERSIZE` bytes. But what happens if the file you want to copy has a size multiple of `BUFFERSIZE`? You write what have been read last time.

`read` return the number of bytes read, so each `write` should try to write this number of bytes:

**Instead of:**

```
        pos = read(src, buffer, BUFFERSIZE);

        //write target file
        while (pos > 0) {
            write(tgt, buffer, BUFFERSIZE);
            pos = read(src, buffer, BUFFERSIZE);
        }
```

**Use:**

```
        pos = read(src, buffer, BUFFERSIZE);

        //write target file
        while (pos > 0) {
            write(tgt, buffer, pos);
            pos = read(src, buffer, BUFFERSIZE);
        }
```

**Same here, instead of:**

```
        //write target file
        while ((pos = read(src, buffer, BUFFERSIZE)) > 0) {
           if (write(tgt, buffer, BUFFERSIZE) != pos) {
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
           }
        }
```

**Use:**

```
        //write target file
        while ((pos = read(src, buffer, BUFFERSIZE)) > 0) {
           if (write(tgt, buffer, pos) != pos) {
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You unconditionally write a full buffer, regardless of how much was read:

```
 //write target file
        while ((pos = read(src, buffer, BUFFERSIZE)) > 0) {
           if (write(tgt, buffer, BUFFERSIZE) != pos) {
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
           }
        }
```

should be:

```
 //write target file
        while ((pos = read(src, buffer, BUFFERSIZE)) > 0) {
           if (write(tgt, buffer, pos) != pos) {
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
           }
        }
```